# Can't push to git using git protocol, origin is https?

Tags: git, config

I just recently setup git-flow. in the instructions I ran the following command:

`git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf git://github`

and I don't think I needed to run that command. I'm not sure if it is the cause but all of the sudden I cannot push a newly created git repo to it's origin. my origin url that I added using `git remote ad origin https://github.com/me/myrepo.git` and as you can see it starts with `https:` but when I go to push it has changed to `git://` as if it is using `git://` instead of `https://`

So why would I get the message that I am trying to use `git://` is there a configuration option or command I can run to ensure it uses https?

Comment: What is the output of 'git remote -v' command?

Comment: `origin git://github.com/me/myrepo.git` for both fetch and push.

Comment: That is why it is trying to use git:// instead of https://

Comment: yes, I understand that, but I set the origin as https, why is it showing my URL with a git protocol?

Comment: Because using the .insteadof config command is not the way to do it probably. You should unset the origin remote and then reset it with https url

Comment: Yes, I have tried: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/me/myrepo.git` as well I have tried removing the origin forst and then adding it back and still nothing is changing.

Comment: Did you perform it as follow: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/ ?

Comment: I will start over with a new repo and try this verbatim when I get to work. Thanks for the link yorammi

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use `ssh` (`git://') you have to create and upload ssh key to your github account.

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)